# Strange behaviour with Master/Detail Flow Template

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am executing these two test cases with the Master/Detail Flow Template:

Test case 1: Select an item from the list -> When it loads, change orientation **one time** -> Press back button.

Test case 2: Select an item from the list -> When it loads, change orientation **two times** -> Press back button.

The first test case results in the onCreate() callback from the ItemListActivity being called when the back button is pressed.
But with the test case 2 it doesn't happens.

In a more general case I noted that if there is an odd number of orientation changes, the onCreate() is called when the back button is pressed, and if the number of orientation changes is even, the onCreate is not called.

I could not figure out why there is this difference between these two test cases.

**Edit:** I'm using a small screen device (with a single-pane layout), not a tablet.